# How many ways can a hand of seven be dealt?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I wish to clear my mind of any doubt.

Some sources I have seen have told me that the answer is $P(52,7)$ as dealt implies order and isn't the same as how many distinct hands can be formed from seven cards. and that the question focuses on a single hand makes it $P(52,7)$

But other sources tell me that it's $C(52,7)$ and that the question is asking for distinct hands.

Can someone tell me whether its $C(52,7)$ or $P(52,7)$ to clear my mind of any doubt? Is the question asking for distinct hands or not? Can someone tell me which it is and how they figured it out?

Comment: both responses are mathematically accurate, making this an English question. its probably loose language by the author rather than a trick question but that's an opinion based on extratextual assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few card games care about the order of cards in your hand. I would say $C(52,7)$ for that reason, as I don't see the distinction that some of your sources do. But ultimately, it is up to whoever wrote any particular exercise, and we can't read minds. And clearly, as there is disagreement, the problem author can't really rely on the word "dealt" to carry an implicit assumption about order. So if it's not explicitly specified, we just have to guess, unfortunately.

It can be salvaged by the fact that often this is just an intermediate calculation, as part of a larger problem ("What is the probability of being dealt all four suits?", for instance). In that case it's more or less up to us whether we care about order, as long as we're consistent we can do it whichever way we feel like.

Comment: Ah I see. If this question had a addendum to it like (This is a poker game). Then we would know 100% that this is a Combinations question correct?

Comment: @SleeperMan23 Poker with 7 cards seems a bit unusual. At any rate, yes, I would say so.

Comment: Never Mind, I see what you wrote above. Thanks for your help. I'm just going to assume combinations from now on unless otherwise stated and not let other people's doubt affect my mind/gut feeling again. Thanks Again!